# How can I remove part of a string when the data to be removed isn't consistent?

Tags: string, query-string

I am attempting to remove the brackets and numbers from the string so that only the college name would be left in the field (sample data below). I have tried to update using the Replace function, but it returns no changes when I run the query. Is it because it's brackets and MSAccess is seeing it as a table? I am trying to use [*] since the data inside is of varying length. It it the * that is causing the break? I'm stuck...  :)

```
[62] BAYLOR
[6124] ARKANSAS
[641] CREIGHTON

UPDATE [TestData] 
SET [TestData].CompleteDescription = Replace([TestData].[CompleteDescription],"[*]","")
```

Answer (score 0):

This would replace the backets and the number and leave just the string:

`Trim(Replace([TestData].[CompleteDescription], Left([TestData].[CompleteDescription], InStr(1, [TestData].[CompleteDescription],"]")), ""))`